# restricting the regular expression only for a line

Tags: java, regex, double-quotes

I have a CSV file below from one of the system.

```
""demo"",""kkkk""
""demo " ","fg"
"     " demo"  "
"demo"
"value1","" frg"   ","vaue5"
"val3",""tttyy "      ",""hjhj","ghuy"
```

Objective is get all the 2 pair double quotes removed and only one set of double quote is allowed like below. The spaces between the sets of double quote is not a fixed value. This has to be handled in a Java program using `replaceAll`

function in Java

```
"demo","kkkk"
"demo","fg"
"demo"
"demo"
"value1","frg","vaue5"
"val3","tttyy","hjhj","ghuy"
```

I tired this on regex101 with `"[ ]*"` and it works for PHP>=7.3 version but not in Java.
Also tried `[\"][\"]|[^\"]\s+[\"]` but still not getting desired output. Any suggestion please for the regular expression which can be used in Java program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on shown sample data, you can use:

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("(?:\\h*\"){2}\\h*", "\"");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jLx5xK/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:\h*\"){2}`: Match a pair of double quotes that have 0 or more whitespaces between them
- `\h*`: Match 0 or more whitespace
- Replacement is just a `"`